# WBS Requested budget and Approved Budget

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I need some help with WBS,

I must to display TOTAL REQUEST and APPROVED BUDGET for WBS Element, but I don't find the needed fields in DB tables, but I know that this values can be updated in transaction CJ30, CJ32 or CJ40. Somebody know which fields in which tables store this information?

Comment: Do you know the screen number of one of these programs that has these fields? You may be able to figure this out on your own by clicking on the field, pressing `F1`, and clicking the `Technical Information` button.

Comment: Hi,
I did this, the field is BPDY-WERT1, but this structure is filled dynamically, and in debugger I cannot find from which table is filled this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the table BPGE (total values for budget), it should contain the information you are looking for. You can get the key field OBJNR for your WBS element from table PRPS.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16438087)

Comment: @Dinesh  Looks like an answer to me.  The question is asking where in a SAP database the information can be found.  The answer points at specific tables that the author claim include the information.  I know enough about SAP to know the answer is plausible but not enough to know if it is correct.  But definitely looks like an answer.